# How to use g:select within taglib in grails

Tags: grails, taglib

Can anyone help me how to use the grails tags like g:select,g:label while creating a taglib functionality.

Following is my code.

I have create a taglib functionality

```
 def dynamicAdvancedSearchTagLib={attrs, body ->
    String beanName = attrs.remove("beanName")
    def bean = request.getAttribute(beanName)
    out << createAdvancedSearchUI(bean)

}
def createAdvancedSearchUI(bean){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb<<"""<fieldset class="search-advanced collapsed"style="border: 1px solid #CCC;padding:0px 21px 0px 21px;border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;min-height:24px;">
    <legend>
        <span id="advancedsearch"> <label for="advancedsearch">Advanced Search
        </label>
        </span>
    </legend>
    <g:form method="post">
    <div id="searchcontent">
        <div class="advanced-content-search">
            <label for="Criteria Name">Criteria Name <span
                class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <select id="searchCriteria" name="searchCriteria" required="">
            *****<option value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
            <option value="1">Something</option>
            <option value="2">Something else</option>
            <option value="3">Another choice</option>**
            </select>***
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 338px;">
            <label for="Enter Your Search Here"> Enter Your Search Here <span
                class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="advancedSearchText"
                value="" required="" />
        </div>

    </div>
    </g:form>
</fieldset>"""
}
```

Here my requirement instead of using the select html tag i need to use the g:select.

I have a  static gsp page i have used g:select as

```
    <g:select id="searchCriteria" name="searchCriteria"
                        from="${SearchCriteria?.values()}"  value="${searchInstance.searchCriteria}"
                        noSelection="${['':'---Select any One---']}" required="" />
```

The same functionality should has to be used while creating the taglib functionality..

If anyone knows how to use the grails tags while createing taglib, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use something like this

```
def attrs=["id":"searchCriteria","name":"searchCriteria"]//fill other values
def formTagLib = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.FormTagLib')
formTagLib.select.call(attrs)
```

[Here](http://www.viaboxxsystems.de/mastering-grails-taglibs) is a tutorial for the above that I found in **Overwrite and reuse** section

As an alternative you can also use

```
out << g.select(attrs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Still I am not getting the overall picture, how to use the grails tags within taglib. There is any sample example or a good tutorial that will take me in the right path.

Comment: @bharathi as mentioned in the code you first need to get an instance of bean where the taglib function resides and then simply call the function. like I did for `formTagLib`

Comment: @bharathi added a tutorial link

Comment: Thank you Ankur.I have tried for textField its working fine.I have a another question.Here in my case searchCriteria is a grrovy class.I nned to access the inList constraints in the taglib.How to do this?

Comment: check this link http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/constraints.html for getting all the constraints

Comment: Can you help me .Sorry for distrubing you frequently.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119284/overwrite-the-the-gselect-tag-in-grails